# Read get request parameter with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to create a script that highlights every instance of a string on a page and that string is received as a get request paramater. I want my page to link to the script like: `<script src="../Scripts/highlightSearch.js" defer></script>` and inside that script I want to have a function like `function highlight(content) {...}` where `content` is the string that I want to be highlighted throughout the page. How can I acess `content` via my script?

Comment: add an event listener, bound to page load, that processes the querystring. If there is a valid querystring and it contains whatever parameter you have assigned to act as the `keyword` perform a `regex` on the entire page - process the results of the regex search to add the highlighting of which you speak

Comment: You need to try and create `highlightSearch.js` by yourself

Comment: @RozzA I already have a working version of the script and can already highlight whatever I want. The problem here is getting the string that I want to be highlighted from the get request

Answer (score 1):

In terms of `"reading the GET request"` there is a relatively new API available that makes reading the querystring parameters trivial. This particular API is [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

If you refer to the compatability table at the bottom you'll notice that Internet Exploder does not support this API so, as a possible alternative, you can use quite a simple function to process the querystring yourself. This following function could ( relatively ) easily be modified to provide similar methods to those found in the `URLSearchParams` api - alternatively [search for a Polyfill](https://www.google.com/search?q=URLSearchParams%20polyfill&oq=URLSearchParams%20polyfill)

```
const getArgs=function() {
    let o={};
    location.search.substring(1).split('&').forEach( function( n ){
        let l=n.indexOf('=');
        if( ~l )o[ n.substring( 0, l ) ]=unescape( n.substring( l + 1 ) );
    });
    return o;
};
```

With those in place when you need to read / mainpulate the querystring you can fork the logic

```
if( 'URLSearchParams' in window ){ /* use methods available to/within the "URLSearchParams" api */ }
else {
    let args=getArgs();
    let query=args.hasOwnProperty('keyword') ? args.keyword ? false;
    if( query ){
        let res=RegExp(pattern[, flags]);
        /* etc */
    }
}
```

That should, I hope, help give a baseline with which to accomplish the stated goal - there are other ways open to you young Jedi. Good luck.

Comment: I used this quick method: https://pastebin.com/5ar5BLR7 (I only have one parameter so I only need to check what's after the first '='). Is there any problem with this solution? It appears to be working fine.